# setInterval function thread is delayed with other setInterval function in Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have two time interval variable in javascript which is executed with 1 sec and is 5 sec. and I give sleep in `myTimer1()` . In that condition current time function `myTimer()`is showing delay to display time on browser. Actually it jumps in second. I want continuous second to display real time. If have any alternate way to display real time than it's greatly appreciated.
I'm facing this type of scenario in MVC based web application.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>A script on this page starts this clock:</p>
<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="demo1"></p>
<script>
var myVar = setInterval(function(){ myTimer() }, 1000);

function myTimer() {
    var d = new Date();
    var t = d.toLocaleTimeString();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = t;
}

var myVar1 = setInterval(function(){ myTimer1() }, 5000);

function myTimer1() { 
document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = "Prashant";
//Calling some function from server side which taking some time to calculated data to showing on browser and it will take some time to load like 2-3 sec. so I use sleep for example.
sleep(3000);
}

function sleep(milliseconds) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
      break;
    }
  }
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Never (ever!) use code wait loops in javascript. You freeze the browser so tight it may never come back (certainly not good to use 100% CPU for no reason :)

Comment: I have edited the question with commented. please see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered simply removing the `sleep()` call entirely? Calls like this can often cause incredibly poor performance and unexpected results (as it ties up your UI thread) :

```
function myTimer1() { 
    document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = "Prashant";
    // This is going to clog up your UI thread and prevent anything from occurring
    // sleep(3000);
}
```

Try removing it and you'll see that your timer runs continuously. If you still need to cause some type of delay, just use the [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) function to handle that (and stopping your current timer).

**Example Without `sleep()`**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>A script on this page starts this clock:</p>
<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="demo1"></p>
<script>
var myVar = setInterval(function(){ myTimer() }, 1000);

function myTimer() {
    var d = new Date();
    var t = d.toLocaleTimeString();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = t;
}

var myVar1 = setInterval(function(){ myTimer1() }, 5000);

function myTimer1() { 
document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = "Prashant";

}

function sleep(milliseconds) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
      break;
    }
  }
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Regarding your Database Comment**

If you are pulling users from a database, you should let the presumably AJAX calls handle when they are finished. If you wanted to pull a new user every 5 seconds, you could consider using an appraoch like this :

```
 // Keep track of how many users you have pulled
 var usersPulled = 0;

 // Every 5 seconds, pull a user
 var userTimer = setTimeout(function(){ pullUser(); }, 5000);

 function pullUser(){
      // Make an AJAX call to pull your specific user
      $.get('/Users/Get', { skip: usersPulled++ }, function(user){
          if(user)
          {
             // Get the user that was pulled and output them
             $('#userlist').append('<p>' + user + '</p>');
          }
          else
          {
             // No user was found, stop your timer
             clearTimeout(userTimer);
          }
     });
}
```

And then your server-side code might look something like the following to pull the "next" user in your database :

```
public string Get(int skip)
{
      // Get the first user available
      var user = _context.Users.OrderBy(u => u.Name).Skip(skip).FirstOrDefault();
      if(user != null)
      {
            return user.Name;
      }
      return null;
}
```

Comment: Basically I just put Sleep for example. data is coming from sql connection and it will take some time.

Comment: If you are pulling the data via Javascript, presumably through an AJAX call, then simply let it handle when it completes on its own. All of the common AJAX calls feature callback functions to let you know when they have completed, so you can simply populate the data within one of these callbacks.

Comment: @PrashantMehta: That was important information for your question. What is the query? What technology does it use? It's surprising if it's a blocking call.

Comment: I'm using Devexpress Dashboard viewer on client side witch take large amout of data to viewing and Dashboardviewer.ReloadData() method is called on every 5 sec. to load new data.

Comment: If that is the case, then you might consider reviewing over their available [client-side documentation](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#Dashboard/CustomDocument17375) for the dashboard to see what kind of events and API it exposes that might make this easier. Additionally, you might want to search on their forums for something like "Reload Dashboard with Javascript".

Comment: yes let me spend some time on devexpress reload() method. thank you @Rion for help and suggest me.

Answer (score 1):

There is only **one** main UI JavaScript thread on browsers, which works on an event queue (job queue) system. When you schedule a timer via `setTimeout` or `setInterval`, when the time is reached that it's supposed to call the callback, what actually happens is that a job (event) is queued for the main UI thread to process when it can.

Your `sleep` function ties up the main UI thread, and so it can't do anything but sit there spinning in your `while` loop. That includes not being able to process callbacks from timers.

Just remove `sleep`. It's not doing anything useful. It *is* doing something *un*useful.

If, for some reason, you wanted to do something three seconds after the call to `timer1`, you'd do it with `setTimeout`:

```
function myTimer1() { 
    document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = "Prashant";
    setTimeout(function() {
        // Do the thing you wanted to do 3 seconds later
    }, 3000);
}
```

---

In a comment you've said:

> Basically I just put Sleep for example. data is coming from sql connection and it will take some time.

Well, it's awfully hard to help you with code we can't see.

Normally, you'd be querying that data via ajax, and so it would be asynchronous (like my `setTimeout` above), and not lock up the browser, unless you told it to be synchronous (hint: don't do that, use the callback).

Comment: Thanks Crowder for answering. //Calling some function from server side witch taking some time to calculated data to showing on browser and it will take some time to load like 2-3 sec. so I use sleep for example.